# How to reuse a branch in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

- I have a branch featureA that got started but not ended.
- Then featureB was requested and done on the master.
- Then the featureB merged into master.
- Now I merged the featureA into master because it needed the featureB.
- Now I want to create a new branch called featureA as it's the same feature but I can't.

What is the best thing to do, or to manage this kind of things in the future?
I don't want to lose my branches... I want to keep the history of every step.
thanks a lot!

```
featB            /--\
master --------------X--X--------
featA       \----------/   \-- I want to continue here the featB and not 
                               creating featB2, without losing the history.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was poorly write too. That was lack of my git knowledge. What I meant it was how to use the same branch name and here is the answer I'm looking for:

- Merge feat A into the master
- Delete feat A branch
- Create the feat A branch again

I didn't know that you could delete a branch or what would happen if was deleted (losing history or so).

From what I currently understand, the branch is just a pointer to some commits. Just to know that commit is not lost somewhere it was given a name (the name of the branch). When you merge a branch into the another the pointer still persist at the commit just before the merge-commit.

I wish I knew it before... but thanks for the comments @jthill

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just figured out: merge the master into the featA and I get featA again.. hope is a good practice

Comment: If the work you're doing this time is unrelated to the work you did last time (e.g. fixing a different bug) it might leave a simpler and just-as-useful history to just make a new branch with the same name, `git branch -f featureA`.  It's not really worthwhile keeping branch names you're not using in the repo; that's what upstream is for :-)

Comment: if I delete a branch I lose my history?

Comment: nope. Once you've merged it in to another branch, its history is also part of that branch.

Comment: well, now I'm just understanding a little bit more of git (: thanks